# Hyper-V did not merge .avhdx after delete checkpoint

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10, checkpoint

I have a Windows 10 laptop that has a Hyper-V host login and that has a VM that I use to native boot to a vhdx file. I hardly ever log into the Hyper-V host but did today to backup the vhdx file and noticed a checkpoint existed, the VM Disk Hard Drive is pointing to an .avhdx instead of the .vhdx file.

I deleted the checkpoint using the Hyper-V gui and now it shows no checkpoints... but VM Disk setting is still pointing to the .avhdx file, which also still exists on disk. I've seen folks say that the avhdx will merge with the vhdx automatically when you shut down the VM...but the VM was already shut down when I deleted the checkpoint.

Also, when in the Hard Drive setting of the VM, there is a warning: `Edit is not available because checkpoints exist for this virtual machine`.

I can still log off the HyperV host login and log back in via the native boot .vhdx.

The .vhdx file has a Date Modified of today, but the .avhdx has a date from Feb 2021. Not sure if that sounds correct...i.e. even though the .avhdx is currently being pointed to in the VM Hard Disk setting, is it not being modified at all on a daily basis when booting to it but the .vhdx is? I can set that as the checkpoint is just config data, not user data...but that is just a guess based on my limited knowledge (I'm a programmer, not a Windows administrator).

I can't manually merge the .avhdx using the Hyper-V gui ([per these instructions](https://www.vembu.com/blog/how-to-merge-hyper-v-checkpoints-with-hyper-v-manager-and-powershell/)) ...it only gives me the option to "Reconnect" when I inspect the .avhdx...and when I try that, I get an error about an Id mismatch. I know there is an option to Ignore the Id mismatch, but decided to do a full backup of the vhdx first and then ask this question while that is happening for the next several hours.

Am I correct in thinking I need to manually merge the avhdx with the Ignore Id mismatch checked ([as per this article](https://thatonecomputerguy.wordpress.com/2016/03/18/windows-10-hyper-v-property-maxinternalsize-does-not-exist-in-class-msvm_virtualharddisksettingdata/))? Then change the Hard Drive setting of the VM to point back to the parent vhdx?

Comment: Precisely the same problem, here, and no answers. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @JerryDodge sorry Jerry, I don't recall what I did and I don't use Hyper V anymore. Best of luck to you.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, and I don't remember how either. But I know it was some weird voodoo, something I would have never expected to fix it.